# Maximize the first $k$-trace of a positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a question that seems simple. But I don't know how to prove it.

Assume $A=(a_{ij})\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ is a real positive definite matrix. Then I want to prove that
$$
\sum^k_{i=1}a_{ii}\leq \sum^k_{i=1}\lambda_{i},
$$
where $\lambda_i$ is the $i$-th largest eigenvalue of $A$.

I am not sure if this is true. If this is true, can anyone give a hint to prove this? If it's not,  can anyone tell me a counter example?

Comment: There are many ways to prove it. Simple proofs can be obtained, for instances, by using Courant-Fischer minimax principle, von Neumann's trace inequality, or Cauchy's interlacing inequality for bordered matrices.

Comment: Is $A$ symmetric?

Comment: Yes. $A$ is positive definite. So it's symmetric.

Comment: What is bordered matrices? Sorry, I can't find it on google.

Comment: @superghostt I felt the conclusion is true for just symmetric matrices. The positive definite condition may be superfluous. For the proof, checking user1551's suggestion (just search Courant-Fischer minimax theorem).

Comment: Thank you! I think I got it. Appreciate your help!

Comment: @superghostt This result is known as the [Schur Horn theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Horn_theorem) (or is part of this result, in any case).

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you! This theorem can directly imply this result.

Comment: @user8675309 Thank you! This can answer my question!